# Installing windows on a separate hard drive (after Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: 11.10, windows, hard-drive

I have an g73jh laptop. Recently I DBan'd the whole laptop and installed Ubuntu 11.10 (on my first HDD, leaving the second one unallocated). Very happy with it, yet still need some stuff from Windows.

Tried to install my Windows7 to the unallocated HDD, no luck - setup unable to create partition.

[image: http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/2907/img0056qo.jpg]

This is from my GParted (My Ubuntu HDD)

[image]

Edit - Is this something to do with the Windows not wanting to be installed on Disk 1, but on disk 0 (where Ubuntu now resides?)

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have any links, I've had a personal experience with that same error message. Do you have any memory cards/flash drives attached? Detach any external memory and reboot back into the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to install Windows 7 in the same partition as Linux Created ext4 file system. Try installing Windows 7 on a different partition. And it looks like you have very little free space for installing Windows. The setup may not run that easy

Comment: Hmm, the ext4 is on SDA, I want to install windows on SDB (unallocated - http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/4116/img0058ese.jpg).